# Refreshing Page with Javascript after upload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have an upload form on the page.  After it submits it doesn't fully refresh the page.  It breaks my datatable because it isn't fully refreshing but still putting the new file in the datatable.  How can I refresh the page completely after upload?

```
$('#FileContents').on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function(event, files, extra) {
        $("#addfilemodal").modal("hide");
        $("#filesuccess").show();
        var fileCount = parseInt($("#filecount").text());
        fileCount += 1;
        $("#filecount").html(fileCount);

        $("#filebody").load("@Url.Action("Attachments", new {collaborationId = Model.Collaboration.Id})");
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are unable to see the actual files on the reloaded page?
What type of files is the user uploading?

Comment: The files are showing.  Basically my datatable controls dissapear when this is ran after upload, but if i refresh the whole page it shows them fine

Comment: I think you can do this with `window.location.href=window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh page.

Add callback to load. In callback initialize/apply your js library (for controlling datatable).

```
 $("#filebody").load("@Url.Action("Attachments", new {collaborationId = Model.Collaboration.Id})");
```

to

```
$("#filebody").load("@Url.Action("Attachments", new {collaborationId = Model.Collaboration.Id})", function( response, status, xhr ) {
 //Apply Datatable js library in here
});
```

Because you are removing elements at #filebody and adding new elements. So you should apply your js library to the new elements.